# How do we limit number of number of snapshots that we get from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter messaging app where I am using Friebase for database. Everytime it loads message, it loads all the message at once. I want it to load only x number of data at once.  I tried using limit but it didn't help.

```
body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('messages')
            .where("threadId", isEqualTo: thread.id)
            .limit(10)
            .snapshots,
```

Comment: what does the above code give you? try doing `where("threadId", isEqualTo: thread.id).orderBy("threadId")
            .limit(10)`

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have the same issue `.limit(1).snapshots().listen((event) {...` not working and not calling `listen` after adding new document / deleting existing document. Kindly share your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I used `.limit(number)`, it works perfectly.
Maybe you should check your where condition.
By the way, your syntax at `.snapshots` is incorrect, it must be `.snapshots()`

Comment: Quang Duy Tran - good catch, I have the same issue `.limit(1).snapshots().listen((event) {...` not working and not calling `listen` after adding new document / deleting existing document. Kindly share your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/duytq94/flutter-chat-demo/blob/master/lib/home.dart at line 269

Comment: Thanks @Quang Duy Tran - we are talking about `snapshots().listen((event) {..` listener but I did not get any code where `snapshots's listener` is being handled in your suggested script. Do we have any other suggestion. Please help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the `take(int count)` on the stream ?

See here: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams